# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una relación sobre la misma tabla con Code First?

Tags: c#, code-first

tengo la siguiente clase con Code First:

```
public class CategoriaProducto
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CategoriaProductoId { get; set; }
    public Guid NegocioId { get; set; }
    public Negocio Negocio { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoriaPadreId { get; set; }
    public string  Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Y lo que quiero lograr es que el campo **CategoríaPadreId** sea una **foranea sobre la misma tabla**, quizás no sea lo mas factible para mi proyecto, pero me sirve para aprender como se hace.

Comment: puedes consultarlo aquí https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the same table (estoy asumiendo que no es una collecion) entonces algo asi deberia funcionar.

```
public class CategoriaProducto
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CategoriaProductoId { get; set; }
    public Guid NegocioId { get; set; }
    public Negocio Negocio { get; set; }
    public Guid? CategoriaPadreId { get; set; }
    public CategoriaProducto Hijo {get; set;}
    public string  Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Luego tienes que configurar esa relacion en el context en el OnModelCreating metodo.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<CategoriaProducto>().
      HasOptional(e => e.Hijo).
      WithMany().
      HasForeignKey(m => m.CategoriaPadreId);
  }
```